# Is there a name for the set of all functions over some domain?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I suppose I'm looking for something like an analogue of $C[0,1]$. Is there a symbolic representation for something like $F[0,1] = \{f(x): f \text{ is defined on } [0,1]\}$?

(This is a matter of curiosity more necessity.)

Comment: What is $C[0,1]$?

Comment: The set of functions continuous over [0,1].

Comment: You mean $C^{0}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Unrelated to $C^n$-smooth curves?

Comment: C(X) is a well recognized notation for continuous functions over a set X. The superscript zero is trivial--it simply implies that it has a 0th order derivative.

Comment: You mean the set of all functions with no structure?  It's not too common to need this because most people want or need structure.  I have seen $F(X,Y)$ for the set of all functions $f: X \to Y$ ($X$ and $Y$ merely sets). I've also seen $\mathrm{Map}(X,Y)$ and variants.

Comment: Sorry ignore me I realise what you’re talking about now

Comment: When the codomain is specified as a set $Y$ then the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ is often written $Y^X$.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that. I simply had a moment where I couldn't think of how I'd write that down, and a cursory search of both the internet and analysis texts didn't turn up anything. 

(For context, I was thinking about nowhere continuous functions that satisfy the intermediate value property, and had a moment of "I don't know how to write the set of which this is a subset")

Comment: I forgot about @EthanBolker 's answer.  That actually is fairly common.

Comment: I think Ethan Bolker's is what you are looking for. It doesn't put any restrictions on the functions. Treats $X$ and $Y$ as raw sets.

Comment: There is no specified codomain, unless OP implicitly means $\mathbb R$ (real-valued functions on a given domain). If the codomain is allowed to be any set, I suspect the result is a proper class (not a set).

Answer (score 3):

To give you an answer to accept, I'm copying Ethan Bolker's comment here, and marking it as "community wiki" so that I get no credit, but you can accept it and thus "close out" the question:

> When the codomain is specified as a set $Y$ then the set of all
>   functions from $X$ to $Y$ is often written $Y^X$.

Comment: But see my comment above

Comment: Indeed; feel free to edit to add this if you like. I suspect that OP *does* mean $\Bbb R$, but if not...